# Ejecutar codigo cuando expire un timer

Tags: c#

tengo una aplicacion que recibe datos enviados desde otro equipo a traves de UDP.
Mi problema, es que necesito saber cuando el otro equipo, deja de enviar los mensajes a traves de la red, ya que al quedarse escuchando el listener, solo hace eso.. y no tengo forma de saber cuando dejar de escuchar para decidir que no hay mas mensajes.

Buscando una solucion, alguien me propuso usar timers, para lo cual inicie un timmer cuando se inicia el listener, y que saltara a otra rutina cando expirara el tiempo (5 seg por ejemplo). el punto es, que el timer nunca ejecuta esta accion.

aca esta el codigo

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int localPort = 15000;
        IPEndPoint remoteSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        UdpClient client = new UdpClient(localPort);
        UdpState state = new UdpState(client, remoteSender);

        // inicia el timmer
        System.Timers.Timer timerUp = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        timerUp.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(CheckStatus);

        // inicia la rececion de mensajes
        client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), state);

        // espera hasta que se pulse una tecla para salir
        // al quedarse esperando aca, el timer nunca se dispara
        Console.ReadKey();
        client.Close();
    }

    static void CheckStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // aca nunca llega el programa, porque el timmer no se dispara
        EstadoCarro.Instancia.IdCarro = 1;
        EstadoCarro.Instancia.Estado = "offLine";
    }


    private static void DataReceived(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        UdpClient c = (UdpClient)((UdpState)ar.AsyncState).c;
        IPEndPoint wantedIpEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e;
        IPEndPoint receivedIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        Byte[] receiveBytes = c.EndReceive(ar, ref receivedIpEndPoint);

        bool isRightHost = (wantedIpEndPoint.Address.Equals(receivedIpEndPoint.Address)) || wantedIpEndPoint.Address.Equals(IPAddress.Any);
        bool isRightPort = (wantedIpEndPoint.Port == receivedIpEndPoint.Port) || wantedIpEndPoint.Port == 0;
        if (isRightHost && isRightPort)
        {
            string receivedText = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
            Console.Write(receivedText);

            if (receivedText.Length > 0)
            {
                EstadoCarro.Instancia.IdCarro = 1;
                EstadoCarro.Instancia.Estado = "Online";
            }
        }

        // reinicia el listener
        c.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), ar.AsyncState);

    }

}
```

aca manejo una clase con el patron singleton, para poder tener una instancia unica en caso que requiera ver mas dispositivos

```
public class EstadoCarro
{
    public static EstadoCarro Instancia = new EstadoCarro();

    private EstadoCarro()
    { }

    public int IdCarro { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }

}
```

Alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No veo en tu código que llames a [`timerUp.Start()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.timers.timer.start(v=vs.110).aspx). Si no indicas al `Timer`que empiece a funcionar, nunca ejecutará `CheckStatus`

Comment: Maestro.. de tanto mirar, no habia caido en cuenta que me faltaba eso.. muchas gracias por la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: De nada @LuisGabrielFabres, son cosas que pasan :)